# Save formatted plain text into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, text, formatting

I have a text file with the following content

```
HDCNWUPC  2014110616414617001509CN  
DT01U00008            Ak Ctn Head Lettuce
```

I need to save this to a sql table with a NVARCHAR column. But I get a distorted content when I retreive the values.

```
HDCNWUPC  2014110616414617001509CN     DT01U00008            Ak Ctn Head Lettuce
```

This is not a html content, but just the plain text from a text file, where the spacing have certain significance.
I need to implement this in c#.
Following code reads the content from text file.

```
var k = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@location);
```

What might be a suitable way ?

Comment: How did you retrieved data and concluded that spacing or line breaks are missing/distorted?

Comment: How you retreive the value??

Answer (score 0):

try with this (add the encoding parameter)

```
var k = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@location,, Encoding.ASCII);
```

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think saving the data is not your problem. Try to run the following code:

```js
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
 Val NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT 
INTO 
 @TestTable
 (Val)
VALUES
(
'HDCNWUPC  2014110616414617001509CN  
DT01U00008            Ak Ctn Head Lettuce '
)

SELECT * FROM @TestTable
```

If you retrieve this value using ssms it should output as desired. However, it depends on your ssms version how the result is displayed, prior versions do not show new lines in grid mode. Please try to output your result in text (CTRL + T)